# javascript in grails paginate

Tags: grails, pagination

can we call javascript function from g:paginate tag . 
I need to call a javascript function when clicked on next page/number .

I'm using like this but no luck :
g:paginate next="Forward" prev="Back" max="100" maxsteps="15" controller="Links" 
action="list" total="${Links.count()}" onclick="return show_waiting();"/>

function show_waiting(){
alert('11111111111');
return true;
}

This is not working .
Can any one help me on this ?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly add a javascript method to the `<g:paginate>` tag. Seems logical since the `<g:paginate>` will render many html  links.

The best way to achieve what you need is  to write a javascript that will listen any 'onclick' events on  elements.

For instance if you code is :

```
<div class="paginateButtons">
  <g:paginate .../>
</div>
```

Then using jQuery, you can add:

```
<g:javascript>
  $(function(){
    $(".paginateButtons a").click(function() {
      alert('11111111111');
    });
  }
</g:javascript>
```

Comment: thanks fabien, your solution working good. I accepted your answer :-)